# tkinter open canvas inside Frame

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have a canvas which is opening in the main window, but I want it to open in the canvas inside the Frame. I tried to add some crazy (as they're in my hands) attributes, but they didn't solve my problem, so I deleted them and have no idea what to do. Could you help me - how could I realize it?

code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Example(Frame): # Frame
 def __init__(self, root):
    Frame.__init__(self, root)

    # ---- for grid ----
    canvas_width = 1000  # MUTABLE!!!
    canvas_height = 1000  # MUTABLE!!!
    self.canvas_width = canvas_width
    self.canvas_height = canvas_height

    self.warehouse_canvas = Canvas(self, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="bisque")
    self.x_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.warehouse_canvas.xview)
    self.y_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.warehouse_canvas.yview)
    self.warehouse_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.y_scrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=self.x_scrollbar.set)
    self.warehouse_canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, canvas_width, canvas_height)) # c_w c_h изменены

    self.x_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
    self.y_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
    self.warehouse_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


    self.warehouse_canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.scroll_start)
    self.warehouse_canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.scroll_move)


    self.draw_grid(self.warehouse_canvas, canvas_width, canvas_height) # !!!

def draw_grid(root, warehouse_canvas, canvas_width, canvas_height):
    for line in range(0, canvas_width, 10):
        warehouse_canvas.create_line([(line, 0), (line, canvas_height)], fill='#d9d9d9', tags='grid_line_width')
    for line in range(0, canvas_width, 10):
        warehouse_canvas.create_line([(0, line), (canvas_width, line)], fill='#d9d9d9', tags='grid_line_height')
    # warehouse_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)               color :  #d9d9d9

def scroll_start(self, event):
    self.warehouse_canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

def scroll_move(self, event):
    self.warehouse_canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = Tk()

   Example(root).grid(row=0, column=0, # положение
                   columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")

   root.mainloop()
```

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEA35.png)

[Where I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKeMF.png)

Is there any way to do it without rewriting the whole code?

Comment: Your question is unclear. It sounds like you're saying you have a canvas in a frame, but what you really want is a canvas in a frame. Could you be more specific about what you mean? Also, the indentation in your code example is broken. Please try to fix it.

Comment: @cody what you have is just a blank tkinter frame you have not written anything for the canvas i guess

Comment: Remove **all** `root..grid_...configure(...` and change to `Example(root).grid(row=1, column=1)`, if you don't want the `Canvas` as big as your Main window.